# Problem creating a new user in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

I try to add a new user from `User Accounts` in the `control panel`.

I click the Add button, and in the wizard that pops up I write a username, and let the domain name stand blank since this should be a local user. Then I click `next`.

I choose standard user on this page (note that the problem occurs regardless of my choice on this page) and click `Finish`.

Then I get the error message:

*The user MACHINENAME\USERNAME could not be granted Standard user access because MACHINENAME\USERNAME does not exist.*

So I'm basically unable to create any local users on my machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try running the following command in cmd: net user username /add
That should then create a user. You can then edit this user though the control panel.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Any idea why this does not work from `User accounts`? It quite useless to have a Add function that fails because the user you try to create does not already exist.

Comment: I have not the faintest idea, sorry.

Comment: @Øyvind: While searching for the error message I found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303593) article which states: "This behavior can occur because the Add New User Wizard is used to add existing domain users to local groups. It cannot be used to create new local user accounts". It sounds like your case (even though it's for XP), because you seem to be on a domain as well.

Comment: @efotinis - That's seems to be exactly the same. So it's because the user name I have entered is not a valid domain user then. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 4):

If you prefer a GUI for this, on the same "Manage User Accounts" control panel, switch to the "Advanced" tab and click the **Advanced** button under "Advanced user management"

Answer (score 3):

1. Click "Start".
2. Type "cmd" into the Search box.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.
   OR
   Click "Run as Administrator".
4. Type the following commands and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after each of them:

   ```
   net users
   net user "john_smith" Access22 /add
   net localgroup administrators "john_smith" /add
   ```

The first command will display all existing account names. Make sure that you see "Administrator".

The second command will create an account called "john_smith" with a password "Access22".
The third command will make "john_smith" an administrator.

Comment: This is the answer that got me out of a pickle! Thank you!